# Google Analytics API - Currency from Google.Adwords in R

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I use library "googleAnalyticsR" to download metric "AdCost" from Google Analytics API .

As I know, the metric allow to transmit data ("Cost") from Google.Adwords.

But the Currency is USD in Google.Adwords.

The AdCost contains RUB in R.

How I can transmit the Currency (USD) via googleAnalyticsR from Google.Adwords?

Answer (score 1):

The currency downloaded is what is set within your Google Analytics web property.  It just downloads a number, then attaches a currency symbol to it, so check that the ad cost is being converted to RUB or $ or if it is just mislabelled.